# Using $this->db->num_rows() in Codeigniter + PostgreSql

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, pdo, codeigniter-3

I'm using Codeigniter 3.0.4 + PostgreSql via PDO.
I just want to get number of rows, that I've just updated. Related cut from Model:

```
public function some_count_update($sid)
{
    $this->db->set('some_field', 'some_field+1', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('id', $sid, FALSE);
    $this->db->update('some_table');
    $this->db->affected_rows();
    return ($this->db->num_rows()>0) ? true : false;
}
```

PHP returns error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_postgre_driver::num_rows() in ...
```

I suppose that problem is, that CI uses php function num_romws(), but for Postgres, php has a special function pg_num_rows(). I tried to modify CI's system class (DB_result > num_rows(), added prefix "pg_" ) but that's doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking affected rows in update  use `$this->db->affected_rows()` instead `$this->db->num_rows()` And your column name in back-tick

```
public function some_count_update($sid)
{
    $this->db->set('some_field', '`some_field`+1', FALSE);// column name in backtick
    $this->db->where('id', $sid);// remove false 
    $this->db->update('some_table');
    return ($this->db->affected_rows()>0) ? true : false;// use affected_rows
}
```

Read https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html

Comment: hm, really, why i tried to check num_rows(), if i can use affected_rows()? Thx for helping, it's works! p.s: that's was stupid question, I know :)

Comment: by the way: in this project i'm not using mysql, postgresql doesn't recognize fieldnames when they are in backticks.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fine :)

```
return ($this->db->where('id', $sid)->get('some_table')->num_rows()>0) ? true : false;
```